# Python XLWT: Write a list into a cell

Tags: python, xlwt

I am trying to write a list into a cell using Python XLWT. Is this possible?

I am currently getting an error:

```
Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'list'>
```

The code:

```
    for x in result:
        sheet1.write(row2,0,x[0])
        sheet1.write(row2,1,x[1])
```

x[1] will be a list.

Thanks!

Comment: Before asking "Can I do X to an Excel file using module M?", ask yourself "Can I do X to an Excel file using the Excel application?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try converting it to a string first:

```
for x in result:
    sheet1.write(row2,0,str(x[0]))
    sheet1.write(row2,1,str(x[1]))
```

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that for the time being, but just wondered if there is a better way

Comment: Other than formatting the list in a different way, or pickling it or something, not sure there's much else you can do. Excel documents don't read Python objects, just strings.